# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is My code :

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class NEwClass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,    "*firefox", "http://gmail.com");

      selenium.start();
      selenium.open("/");

    }


}
```

I seem to be getting error :

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session:"

and I am not sure why. Thank you in advance for your answers!

> objc[6744]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1002704c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1003384e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: 
>       
>       
>         
>         
>         
>         
>         
>         
>           var json = Object.freeze('{"version":"3.6.0","type":"Standalone","consoleLink":"/wd/hub"}');

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:109)
    at NEwClass2.main(NEwClass2.java:9)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze('{"version":"3.6.0","type":"Standalone","consoleLink":"/wd/hub"}');
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:109)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:272)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:100)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What have you tried? What part of the code causes the problem?

Comment: You're getting a whole lot more error message than that. Post it.

Comment: I launched the server through terminal, ive been searching other forums but none of the answers seem to help

Comment: I added the full error above